# packing/unpacking binary data using as3

Tags: python, actionscript-3

I am porting a python app that makes use of these functions
http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html to read a 32-bit little value.

what would be the AS3 equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that the standard AS3 library has is the `.readXXX()` and `.writeXXX()` methods in the [`ByteArray`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) class. But the interface is, by not means, as comprehensive phython's `struct.unpack` and `struct.pack` (or other languages' byte packing implementations).

Without some data, it's difficult to say if `ByteArray` would be enough.